# I can't access json sub data

Tags: react-native

```
"menus": [
{
  "key": "main",
  "description": "Siparişinizi oluşturun",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "İndirimli Menüler",
      "caption": "İndirimli Menüler",
      "image": "./images/kirmizi-et-menu.jpg",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Kırmızı Et Menü",
          "caption": "Kırmızı Et Menü",
          "price": 2095,
```

I can't access this json data this way. What should I do?

```
     renderMenuList = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{item.items[0].items[0].name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList
          renderItem={this.renderMenuList}
          data={data.menus}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
```

I get the error 'undefined is not an object"
I am getting the main items data. but I cannot get the data below it.

Answer (score 1):

can you try whit this:

```
 <SafeAreaView>
    <FlatList
      renderItem={this.renderMenuList}
      data={menus}
    />
```

just with pass `data` because the `prop data` of `FlatList` just receive array, and if you put `data.menu` you will pass an object

so, if you wanna call the items for example `Kırmızı Et Menü` in your component `renderMenuList`, I think you should call this way

```
   renderMenuList = ({item, index}) => {
return (
  <View>
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

and another thing, you should change this prop in your component `FlatList`:

- `data={data.menus}` to `data={menus.items}`

something like this:

```
<FlatList
      renderItem={this.renderMenuList}
      data={menus.items}
    />
```

Comment: So how can I call menus in this case

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I think you problem is on `renderMenuList`. Try this:

```
renderMenuList = menus.forEach((item, index) => { ... });
```